# Setting up a .htaccess file subdomains but also non www. to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

We have an Opencart web shop setup that uses various sub domains. I'm trying to configure our .htaccess file to do the following but can't quite get over the finish line.

Our site is setup this way:

**Main Domain:**

ourdomain.com

**Sub Domains x 10**

sub1.ourdomain.com

sub2.ourdomain.com

sub3.outdomain.com

**Here's what must happen:**

All visitors to the http version of the main domain or the subdomains must be redirected to https.

Visitors to any of the sub domains must be redirected to https://subdomain.ourdomain.com but without the www.

Visitors to https://ourdomain.com must be redirected to https://www.ourdomain.com.

Basically I always need visitors to the main domain to be directed to the www. version to ensure that the CSS files render correctly. Icons and graphics are missing if www. is missing.

I've currently got it configured to redirect all visitors to https but I don't know how to apply www. to only the main domain.

Hope that all makes sense.

**My current code:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ourdomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules :

```
RewriteEngine on

#Redirect "http://sub.example.com" to "https://sub.example.com"#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#Redirect "http://example.com" or "http://www.example.com"  to "https://www.example.com"#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Replace **example.com** with **yourdomain.com** in the RewriteConds above.

Comment: Thanks for your response starkeen.

We're nearly there but your code above directs sub1.mydomain.com to www.sub1.mydomain.com which is no good.

I'm going to try and understand your code and see if I can figure it out myself in the meantime. Will post back in here if I solve it before you get chance to respond.

Comment: @Rhorne Sorry, there was a typo in the 2nd RewriteCond. Actually it was overriting your subdomain to the main domain. I have updated the condition. please see the edit.

Comment: starkeen I have another issue now which is a result of forcing all versions of my site into https:// - graphics and icons are displaying as a square icon suggesting a missing link. 

In researching this I've come across the following fix, but this doesn't seem to work for me, can I trouble you to have a look and see if this needs modifying to match your rewrite rules?

    # Fix Icons
    <FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>

Comment: Actually, don't worry.

This has opened up a whole other host of issues relating to Opencart as my SEO-friendly URLs no longer work, and every product from every sub domain now redirects away from the sub domain. 

This is going to require more work.